# Remove license from unavailable/down/deleted ESXi host

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vsphere-client

I need to remove/unassign a paid license from an ESXi host (6.5) that is not anymore used.

As this host became unresponsive, the hosting company removed it completely, and **I cannot access to the ESXi host anymore** to "safely and correctly" removing the license, and put back a demo license.

How can I remove this unused licensed from this unavailable/down/deleted ESXi host, if this host is **shut down/gone forever** ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to remove the license from non-operational host. Simply apply this license to your new ESXi host and leave in peace :)

Comment: So, if i understand well, as long as an host is non-operational, it does not "count" as the total of allowed licenses ?

Comment: Correct. As soon as old host is not present in your current vSphere cluster, you are OK.

Comment: Thanks ! I assume that this "vSphere cluster" is only a virtual concept @ VMWare, and that they regularly "check" for "how many" hosts are using the same license ?